# How do I avoid this PHP Script causing a server standstill?

Tags: php, curl, daemon

I'm currently running a Linux based VPS, with 768MB of Ram.

I have an application which collects details of domains and then connect to a service via cURL to retrieve details of the pagerank of these domains.

When I run a check on about 50 domains, it takes the remote page about 3 mins to load with all the results, before the script can parse the details and return it to my script. This causes a problem as nothing else seems to function until the script has finished executing, so users on the site will just get a timer / 'ball of death' while waiting for pages to load.

**(The remote page retrieves the domain details and updates the page by AJAX, but the curl request doesnt (rightfully) return the page until loading is complete.

Can anyone tell me if I'm doing anything obviously wrong, or if there is a better way of doing it. (There can be anything between 10 and 10,000 domains queued, so I need a process that can run in the background without affecting the rest of the site)

Thanks

Comment: "nothing else seems to function". Just other urls parsed by php, or all urls(eg images too)?

Comment: 1) By nothing else seems to function I mean just urls parsed by PHP. Images load without issue.

Comment: 2) I'm already batch processing the process from a mysql DB. The problem is anytime it picks up some unprocessed domains and starts to check 50, no pages can be loaded on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more sensible approach would be to "batch process" the domain data via the use of a cron triggered PHP cli script.

As such, once you'd inserted the relevant domains into a database table with a "processed" flag set as false, the background script would then:

1. Scan the database for domains that aren't marked as processed.
2. Carry out the CURL lookup, etc.
3. Update the database record accordingly and mark it as processed.

   ...

To ensure no overlap with an existing executing batch processing script, you should only invoke the php script every five minutes from cron and (within the PHP script itself) check how long the script has been running at the start of the "scan" stage and exit if its been running for four minutes or longer. (You might want to adjust these figures, but hopefully you can see where I'm going with this.)

By using this approach, you'll be able to leave the background script running indefinitely (as it's invoked via cron, it'll automatically start after reboots, etc.) and simply add domains to the database/review the results of processing, etc. via a separate web front end.

Comment: Thanks Middaparka

I'm already batch processing the process from a mysql DB as you've described above. 

The problem is, anytime it picks up some unprocessed domains and starts to check 50, no pages can be loaded on the site until the process is complete.

Comment: @thatguy It could just be that your VPS instance is hitting its resource cap (you might have 768Mb of RAM, but what about CPU usage, etc.) I presume reducing the number of domains it attempts to batch makes no difference? (i.e.: Is it just the load of the processing that's causing the problem or the duration?)

Comment: Hi,

Thats Correct. The number of domains affects the time the script spends executing but it's the processing load causing the 'freeze up'.

I'm looking at the % memory (0.9) and %cpu (0.2) so it doesnt seem excessive.

I've noticed that other sites on the same vps but under a different name operate fine during the point when the temporary 'crash' happens

Comment: @thatguy Sounds very much like a resource cap then. (Are those figures from "top" - if so, they may well be for the machine as a whole.) Do you have any VPS/container monitoring software you can use to confirm? (Virtuozzo or similar.) Either way it sounds like an upgrade/change of provider might be necessary. :-(

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the ideal solution, but if you need to trigger this process based on a user request, you can add the following at the end of your script.

```
set_time_limit(0);
flush();
```

This will allow the PHP script to continue running, but it will return output to the user. But seriously, you should use batch processing. It will give you much more control over what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'm sorry but Im an idiot! :)

I've loaded the site in another browser (FF) and it loads fine.

It seems Chrome puts some sort of lock on a domain when it's waiting for a server response, and I was testing the script manually through a browser.

Thanks for all your help and sorry for wasting your time.

CJ

Comment: Bizarre. Still, you live and learn. :-) Incidentally, I'd update your question with the above information rather than add it as an answer. (Otherwise, people are a lot less likely to notice it.)

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with others that you should consider processing these tasks outside of your webserver, in a more controlled manner, I'll offer an explanation for the "server standstill".

If you're using native php sessions, php uses an exclusive locking scheme so only a single php process can deal with a given session id at a time. Having a long running php script which uses sessions can certainly cause this.

You can search for combinations of terms like:
php session concurrency lock session_write_close()

I'm sure its been discussed many times here. I'm too lazy to search for you. Maybe someone else will come along and make an answer with bulleted lists and pretty hyperlinks in exchange for stackoverflow reputation :) But not me :)

good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how your code is structured but you could try using `sleep()`. That's what I use when batch processing.